# How to include the preferred_username claim in Id_token

Tags: angularjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

When I log into Azure AD B2C I don't get the preferred_username claim included id_token. Is there a way to configure this from the Azure portal? Pretty sure I would get this claim in regular Azure AD OIDC implicit flow.

I've tried looking at custom claims but it seems like this should be a built-in claim that gets included or mapped to some attribute.

Comment: Hi @Colin. What attribute do you want to issue in the `preferred_username` claim?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett ideally i just need the email address entered for the social account as the `preferred_username`. As a work around I'm including a passed email address as the `login_hint` extra parameter when redirecting to Azure to collect login creds. I noticed if you have `displayableId` it does this for you. But since B2C doesn't seem to supply this claim for free I had to find a different way.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure//active-directory/develop/msal-net-aad-b2c-considerations#known-issue-with-azure-ad-b2c) with B2C and the MSAL libraries.

From the [MSAL .NET wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AAD-B2C-specifics#caching-with-b2c-in-msalnet): B2C does not return a value in the IdToken for the preferred_username because of limitations with the social accounts and external identity providers (IdPs). Azure AD returns a value for preferred_username because it knows who the user is, but for B2C, because the user can sign in with a local account, Facebook, Google, GitHub, etc...there is not a consistent value for B2C to use for preferred_username. To unblock MSAL from rolling out cache compatibility with ADAL, we decided to use "Missing from the token response" on our end when dealing with the B2C accounts when the IdToken returns nothing for preferred_username. MSAL must return a value for preferred_username to maintain cache compatibility across libraries.

If you want to display a value in the UI, you should be able to use the login hint to pass in a username to pre-fill the sign-in UI. As noted in this MSAL .NET [issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1731#issuecomment-658320529).

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure//active-directory/develop/msal-net-aad-b2c-considerations#known-issue-with-azure-ad-b2c) with Azure AD B2C.

> This is because Azure AD B2C does not return a value in the IdToken
>   for the preferred_username because of limitations with the social
>   accounts and external identity providers (IdPs).Azure AD returns a
>   value for preferred_username because it knows who the user is, but for
>   Azure AD B2C, because the user can sign in with a local account,
>   Facebook, Google, GitHub, etc. there is not a consistent value for
>   Azure AD B2C to use for preferred_username.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure//active-directory/develop/msal-net-aad-b2c-considerations#workarounds) is the Workarounds.